# How to pass data from children to parent components in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I need to build a multi-page form using React to collect some data from a user. When a user submits this form, I want to make a post request to an API and pass the data along.

I found [this](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/v5.12.2/docs/data/material/getting-started/templates/checkout) MUI template, and I would like to use it. The template has a form (the parent component), with multiple subpages (the children components). Since I want to send all the data as part of one API request, my assumption is that the form (parent component) should be the one making the request.

What can I do to make the parent component know about the values a user passes into the child components, so I can include that information in the request?

Comment: In general, if a parent component needs to know about the state of the child components then the parent component would own that state and would pass its state values to the child components as props.  Alternatively, the state itself could be more global (Redux, `useContext`, etc.) and both the parent and children could both access that state.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that this is usually an anti pattern.
I'd recommend  a look at the [suggested way](https://react.dev/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context) to handle this.

Local storage would also aid you to prevent making someone restart the form if they refresh the page

That being said if you define state in the parent and pass down the setState with props you can achieve this behavior.

```js
    //in Parent.js
    import Child from "./Child"
    import { useState } from "react";
    
    export default function Parent() {
    
      const [data,setData] = useState('');
    
      const handleClick = (param) => {
        setData(param)
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>{data}</h1>
          <Child data={data} sendToParent={handleClick} />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

```js
    // in Child.js
    import { useState } from "react";
    
    export default function Child(props) {
      const { sendToParent } = props;
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    
      return (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            /* notice how strange this code looks, 
           we're basically trying to outsmart the rerender */
            setCount(count + 1);
            sendToParent(`Child clicked ${count + 1}`);
          }}
        >
          Click me
        </button>
      );
    }
```

There's a codesandbox if you want to [interact with it](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-meninsky-85ziw5?file=/src/Child.js:0-434).